# How to move head to left in ParticleHead.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, frontend

I want to move particle head to left in particlehead.Js . Please help me.
This is the github repository: https://github.com/vs811/RightCust
This is the live preview: http://cdn.rawgit.com/vs811/RightCust/vs811-patch-5/indexnew.html

ParticleHead is on third slide

Answer (score 0):

Did you give particlehead.js a look? I found these two variables about 20 lines in.

```
var windowHalfX = site.Width / 2;
var windowHalfY = site.Height / 2;
```

Try changing these to move the head where you want it to go.
If that doesn't work, take a look at the style.css file and modify the particle head class shown here:

```
.particlehead {
    background: #000000;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but this didnt worked. I found temporary solution by decreasing the width of section. But still not able to understand how to move the head.

Answer (score 0):

Replace only this 2 lines (negative value after "="):

```
   function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
       mouseX = -( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
       mouseY = -( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;
    }
```